# work with fifo in c++ ( blocking read)

Tags: c++, c, linux, fifo

What I want to do :

1.Create and  open for writing in.fifo by process1

2.Open in.fifo for reading in process2

3.Write from cin to in.fifo by process1 line

4.Read and cout line by process2

5.When input "exit" to cin (process2), it closed file in.fifo, delete it and exit

6.process2 exit, because in.fifo has no writer

In my programs process2 doesn't exit. In c it works with read,write when O_NONBLOCK is clear , but I want to do  it in c++

write.cpp:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    std::ofstream fifo;
    fifo.open("/home/fedor/projects/fifo2/in",ios::out);
    if(! fifo.is_open() ){
        std::cout << " error : cannot open file " << std :: endl; 
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << " file open " << std :: endl; 
    std::string   line;   
    while (line.compare("exit") != 0 ){
         std::getline(cin, line);
         fifo << line << endl;
          /* do stuff with line */
    }
    fifo.close();
    remove("/home/fedor/projects/fifo2/in");
    return 0;
}
```

read.cpp:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    std::ifstream fifo;
    fifo.open("/home/fedor/projects/fifo2/in",ifstream::in);
        if(! fifo.is_open() ){
        std::cout << " error : cannot open file " << std :: endl; 
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << " file open " << std :: endl; 
    std::string   line;
    bool done = false;
    while (!done)
        {
        while (std::getline(fifo, line))
        {
            cout << line << endl;
            /* do stuff with line */
        }
        if (fifo.eof())
        {
            fifo.clear();  // Clear the EOF bit to enable further reading
        }
        else
        {
            done = true;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I can't find where I can read about blocking read by streams like http://linux.die.net/man/3/read about blocking read

If process2 closed if input "exit", like process1 is that a life lock ? (Is it blocking on read, or just trying and trying to read )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want using C++ standard library, because in C++ there is no notion of processes and file sharing. You have to use OS-specific APIs, which most likely are C (like `open()`) but in theory they can be C++.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I have programm on c, that works like I want. How I can use functions like open() in c++ ?

Comment: @fedden Just use them like you do in C.

Comment: Thanks, all working. In C++ need to include some different libs :))

Answer (score 0):

Your reader appears to explicitly ignore an eof, instead clearing the end of file condition, and continuing. You're saying that your reader isn't exiting. Of course it's not, you're explicitly clearing EOF and continuing. It's going to exit only on an error reading from the FIFO, which is going to be a fairly unusual event.

If you want to exit on an EOF, you'll have to explicitly do that. Or, if you want to terminate on receiving the exit message, your writer isn't going to send it. When the writer itself receives a typed "exit", it terminates without writing it to the fifo (and your reader needs to check for that).

Comment: Thanks for answer!

I whant to exit on EOF, when file has not writers.
Why I have EOF when file have writer ? 

If I exit on "exit", is it life-lock? (thread stops on EOF, or just trying to read in loop)

If I exit not on EOF,